# Use of verb after WHO

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

I have a doubt regarding the use of the verb "has or have " after **who** in the following sentence,

> I request you my work to be evaluated by Mr. Bender and Mr. Joseph who has expertise in the work done by me.

Please help

Comment: *I request you my work to be* is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Could you make it grammatical

Comment: I don't know what it's trying to express—it could mean several different things. But the closest I can come up with, which uses most of the words, is *I request of you that you have my work evaluated by . . .*

Comment: @JasonBassford I want to say: `I request you that my work should should be evaluated by....`

Comment: That different phrasing also makes no sense. Specifically *I request you* is wrong. It should be *I request **of** you* or *I request **that** you*. But I also don't understand what you're trying to say in the rest—because ***you*** are neither Mr. Bender nor Mr .Joseph. So, who are you asking to perform the evaluation? If it's not ***you***, then why use that pronoun?

Comment: @JasonBassford, I am suggesting two persons to an authority for evaluation of  a report.

Comment: Then where does ***you*** come in? Why isn't it just *I request my work be evaluated by Mr. Bender and Mr. Joseph*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it is written now is indeed confusing. The *has* suggest that only Mr. Joseph has expertise, but then a comma could've been added:

> I request you my work to be evaluated by Mr. Bender, and by Mr. Joseph who has expertise in the work done by me.

This would probably not have confused you.

If both have expertise, you must use *have*.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ell Stack.

As you are referring to two people (in third person) in your sentence, you should use the plural verb have after who. You use the singular verb has after who when you are talking about a person (in third person).